# Set value of array input php

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I have a code like this :

## stuff 1

```
<input type="text" id="stuff" name="stuff[]" />

<input type="text" id="more_stuff" name="more_stuff[]" />
```

## stuff 2

```
<input type="text" id="stuff" name="stuff[]" />

<input type="text" id="more_stuff" name="more_stuff[]" />
```

---

I need to set the input, what i know to set the value is:

```
$string="arifin";

document.getElementById("stuff").value=$string;
```

---

But that code change the first row only(the first input stuff). How to set the value of the second stuff input ?

Comment: IDs should be unique throughout the page. `document.getElementById` will get you the first matching element only. You need to loop through the elements (get them using their name) and set the value individually.

Comment: you need to loop through that id to set values

Comment: @DhanuK first it needs to be a `class` instead

Comment: yes @Adelin ,exactly or we can also use class instead of id

Comment: @DhanuK .. Or that

Comment: can you give me an example how to use a class? @DhanuK

Comment: @Arifin_ see answer

Answer (score 0):

You can select all the elements as document.querySelectorAll('[id^=more_stuff]')

```
var ele = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=more_stuff]');
$string="arifin";
for(var i in ele){
   ele[i].value=$string;
}
```

If you want to use for class just change as

```
document.querySelectorAll('.classname');
```